# having more than one root in a closure table model?

Tags: mysql, sql

As you know, categories will look like this in hierarchical model.

```
Books             Electronic Devices
>Programming       >Apple
>>C++              >>MacBook pro
>Cars              >Samsung
>Cocking           >Asus
```

etc...
I have created a `categories` table with a `category_closure` table.
So i have these two tables:

```
'For category_closure table:'
id, parent_id, title, etc...
"parent_id is null by default"

And for category_closure table:
ancestor, descendant, depth
```

I have watched lots of articles about closure table model but they didn't show how to get Full tree path of a table that have more than one parent_id with `null` value or by simple, have more than one root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to solve a similar problem a few years ago, and I ended up creating a hybrid solution based upon [this article by Mike Hillyer on the Nested Set Model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). I have no idea if this will be compatible with your table models, but at the very least it should be an interesting and informative read. The basic idea is this:

Currently you are using a model called the adjacency list model, in which each node contains a reference to it's parent. This can be good for shallow hierarchies, where you only have a few levels of data, or if you only need to get the direct children of a particular node.

If you want to be able to get all descendants of a particular node (for example, getting a list of books on all subjects), the adjacency list model becomes a bit unwieldy. For these instances I would recommend using the nested set model. The nested set model gives each node a "Left" value, and a "Right" value, based upon it's position in the hierarchy (the article walks you through how those values are assigned with more detail than I could hope to replicate in my answer). So, if you want to select all descendants of a node, you simply look for nodes whose left (or right, it doesn't matter) value is BETWEEN the left and right values of your target node.

In my particular solution I implemented both models in my table, and did my selects based upon the most convenient model for the data I needed. This did add a small amount of overhead to update operations in my data, but for the application I was working on that was an acceptable tradeoff.

I hope that helps!